# Hosting for the Fastest Download Speeds

Tags: hosting, performance

Hello I'm developing an iPhone app that downloads some reasonably chunky database files (10M-50M) my current server is hosted in the US, I am based in the UK, my download speeds aren't great, somewhere in the region of 40-50k/second on a connection I've seen run to 300k with other downloads. I am wondering if anyone knows of a way of finding hosting which would have high download speeds worldwide (US, Asia and Europe) or which would be the best compromise? Or any other solutions? Essentially I want to improve the user experience by improving download times.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at CDN solutions. few examples:

- [rackspace](http://www.rackspacecloud.com/cloud_hosting_products/files)
- [amazon](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/)

and many others

Comment: Rackspace is also my recommendation

Answer (score 0):

Where is your server exactly located? If you're planning on staying in the US, NYC will be your best bet.

[ReliableSite](http://www.reliablesite.net/v3/dedicated.asp) has excellent connectivity to the UK.